# Class with 2 associative array with foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a situation that i can't understand. I have this associative array for example

```
$assocHeroes = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Markos",
        "type" => "boy",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Jim",
        "type" => "boy",
    ),
   array(
        "name" => "Maria",
        "type" => "liz",
   )
);

$wallOfHeroes = array();

foreach ($assocHeroes as $assocHero){
    foreach ($assocHero as $name=>$type){
       $hero = new Hero($name,$type);
       echo $hero->taunt();

       $wallOfHeroes[]=$hero;
    }
}


print_r($wallOfHeroes);
```

as you can see from the code `$hero = new Hero($name,$type);` i have also a Class Hero. In this Class i have only one function `taunt();` and more specifically

```
public function taunt() {
    return "My name is {$this->name}!".PHP_EOL;
}
```

so i just want to get `My name is Markos` `My name is Jim` .. etc.. i don't know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly since you have not given the code of your class and how are you assigning values from the constructor, it is difficult to tell you where is it that you are mistaken.

I have taken the liberty to define the class as per your question outline and attached a working set of code. This should work.

```
<?php

class Hero
{
    public $_name;
    public $_type;

    public function __construct($name,$type) 
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_type = $type;
    }
    public function taunt() 
    {
        return "My name is ".$this->_name."!<br>";
    }
}
$assocHeroes = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Markos",
        "type" => "boy",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Jim",
        "type" => "boy",
    ),
   array(
        "name" => "Maria",
        "type" => "liz",
   )
);
$wallOfHeroes = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($assocHeroes);$i++)
{
    $hero = new Hero($assocHeroes[$i]["name"],$assocHeroes[$i]["type"]);
    echo $hero->taunt();
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in foreach, make sure the value can print, for debugging your code

```
foreach ($assocHeroes as $assocHero){ 
   foreach ($assocHero as $key => $value){
         echo $key ." ". $value . "<br>";
   }
}
```